# MongoDB - Can I shard all new db's (Created by application) automatically?

Tags: mongodb

My team will deploy a new version of our app (Capture social media posts, hashtags etc.) they create a different DB for each user and we may have thousands of collections on each DB. I read all mongoDB shard documentation and I saw that I can only shard an collection or one DB at time,  I'm missing something ?

We will start this new version fresh, without any databases and we will grow from 0 again (For now, we have 23k users) but we will escalate this number really quickly (100.000+ at the end of the year)

My question is: I really need a Shard cluster ? (My test setup have 3 shards with 3 microshards, 3 config servers and 2 mongos) for now, in production, i have a large server doing all the hard work but i dont want to scale to top, the horizontal scale is  the best choice, i think.

Can I shard all my databases automatically or I really need to do that one by one doing the shard key procedure and so. ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I reading this right? You create a new database for every single user? I think your implementation is incorrect. I think you should have a single collection of users and a collection for each KIND of social media post (facebook, twitter, instagram, etc)

Comment: Using this design you will end up with close to a billion (1,000,000,000) collections!

Comment: let me just correct a info: It's one DB and one collection per user, sorry about the wrong info.

What if i create only one db with one single and big collection. You guys think that i will have limitation problems or it will be a best solution for sharding ?

** We use a setup with two DBs, the first keep the user info (MySQL) and the second, social media data (Mongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading correctly. What you intend to do is so far away from what any sensible person would do that MongoDB doesn't offer any tools to support this. If you really want to go with this WTF solution, your application will be responsible to set up sharding for each collection it creates. This forces you to give administration permission to the application (despite what any security guides recommend).

*"Will you really need a sharded cluster"* - that depends on how much data you will have and how often you query it with what kind of query. But it is unlikely to work anyway, because your sharded cluster will have to manage (100,000 databases* 1.000 collections) = a hundred million collections. MongoDB is not designed for scaling in *that* direction. The cluster will likely be so busy with bookkeeping that you won't really see any notable performance gain.

It is also questionable if clustering would even theoretically make sense. Clustering is usually only useful when you have very large collections. But in your scenario where your data is so heavily fragmented into a million collections, each individual collection is unlikely to be very large.

If you really want to go this route, it might in fact be a better solution to separate the databases physically by assigning each user to a database server.

---

Or you could just build a database architecture like a normal team would with one database for all users and one collection per type of document. You would then speed up lookups by creating a compound index on user and whatever criteria you used to tell which database a document belonged to. This index *might* also be a good shard key.

Comment: Thanks, Philipp,

What if i create only one db with one single collection. You think that i will have limitation problems or it will be a best solution for sharding ?

Comment: @JulianoPiassa I know nothing about how your data looks, so I can't tell what's the best solution for *you*. Most MongoDB projects have one database with a handful of collections, where each collection holds one type of document. If you have only one type of documents, you would only need one collection.